# How to debug wince6.0 r2 image using KITL?

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I am new in wince .I have a image in wince 6.0 r2.I want to debug that image and print messages.I know only that KITL is use for debugging.... but how to use that?

Answer (score 2):

"How to use KITL" is a very large question, one that isn't easily answered in a format like this.  First, does your target BSP support KITL?  Not all do (though debugging without it is not fun at all) and if your platform doesn't, then trying to get it working is likely way more effort than you want to spend.  So the first step is to talk to the OEM or check the docs.

Next, does the platform support KITL from the bootloader, or from OS startup?  That's another thing the OEM will be able to tell you.  Usually the bootloader has to be told to enable KITL and to look for BOOTME messages from Platform Builder.  How this is done is very platform dependent and, again, you'll want to consult the platform docs or the OEM.

Next, you need to build an OS image that supports KITL.  That's in the properties of the build.  Just turn it on and re-sysgen.

Once that's done, you should be able to tell PB to connect, boot the target and a KITL connection will be made.  The OS image will get downloaded and you're off and debugging.  Of course there are options and different levels of what may or may not be supported, especially if you're trying to do network stuff at the same time.

Most of this is covered in the Platform Builder docs, in MSDN and in the platform team's various blogs.  I'd recommend doing a search for 'KITL' in your favorite search engine.

But again, step one is to ask your OEM about how to set up things on your specific target hardware to use KITL.